# onLayout() behavior in Android

Tags: java, android, layout, xamarin

I have my custom view which will add button controls dynamically. In my `onLayout` method, I have a logic something like below.

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    for (int i = 0; i < this.getChildCount(); i++) {
        this.getChildAt(i).layout(left, top, right / 2, top + 200);
    }
}
```

this crops my button control instead of shrinking. will `layout()` change the width of the View or it will just crop it.

Do I need to call measure for all the child in `onMeasure()`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you call layout() with the same parameters for each child view?

Comment: It is just an example. I need clarification on "will layout() set the width of the View or it will just crop it."

Comment: I have no idea what "crop" do you mean

Answer (score 1):

Yes, generally speaking, measure tells views how big to be, and layout tells views where to be. If you override layout without measure, the views will be drawn full size in the wrong position, and will be cropped by the canvas.

Comment: I implemented a ViewGroup called InputField and placed a TextView and EditText in it. I didnt have to call measureChild on them. Infact measureChild(editText,w,h) did nothing! And I dont have to call drawChild either. I only had to lay them out.